# Cache partial view using Umbraco CachedPartial for different model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, umbraco

I'm using [CachedPartial](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Templating/Mvc/partial-views#caching) html helper which caches that partial view.

```
@Html.CachedPartial("PartialView", MyModel, 3600, true);
```

In my view, I have the following situation:

```
@Html.CachedPartial("PartialView", MyModel, 3600, true);

@Html.CachedPartial("AnotherPartialView", MyModel1, 3600, true);

@Html.CachedPartial("PartialView", MyModel3, 3600, true); // I want to reuse partial view
```

Seems that first and third view are identically because of `CachedPartial` ...

How to make cached partial by model parameter ?

I tried to use

```
@Html.CachedPartial("PartialView", MyModel, 3600, true, false, new ViewDataDictionary(MyModel3));
```

but same thing.

---

**Edit**: I used a different approach than DZL and it works

```
  public static IHtmlString CachedPartial( this HtmlHelper helper, string partialViewName, object model, string cacheKey = null )
  {
     if ( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( cacheKey ) ) {
        return helper.CachedPartial( partialViewName, model, AppSettings.PartialCachingSeconds, true );
     }

     Func<object, ViewDataDictionary, string> fc = ( o, v ) => cacheKey;

     return helper.CachedPartial( partialViewName, model, AppSettings.PartialCachingSeconds, true, contextualKeyBuilder: fc );
  }
```

and then

```
@Html.CachedPartial("PartialView", MyModel, "a_key");

@Html.CachedPartial("AnotherPartialView", MyModel1);

@Html.CachedPartial("PartialView", MyModel3, "another_key"); // I want to reuse partial view
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want that you will need to create your own implementation of `CachedPartial`, something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
using Umbraco.Web;
using System.Web;
using System.Runtime.Caching;

public static class CachedPartialExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString MyCachedPartial(
        this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
        string partialViewName,
        object model,
        int cachedSeconds,
        bool cacheByPage = false,
        string cacheKey = null,
        ViewDataDictionary viewData = null
    )
    {
        var newCacheKey = "fpc-";  //prefix to know which keys to clear on page publish (in Bootstraper.cs file)
        newCacheKey += partialViewName;
        if (cacheByPage)
        {
            newCacheKey += "page-" + UmbracoContext.Current.PageId;
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cacheKey))
        {
            newCacheKey += "key-" + cacheKey;
        }

        var result = MemoryCache.Default.Get(newCacheKey) as MvcHtmlString;
        if(result == null)
        {
            result = htmlHelper.Partial(partialViewName, model, viewData);
            MemoryCache.Default.Add(new CacheItem(newCacheKey, result), new CacheItemPolicy
            {
                AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(cachedSeconds)
            });
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

And then you will be able to provide your own keys for cache:

```
@Html.MyCachedPartial("PartialView", Model, 60, cacheKey: "model1key", cacheByPage: true)
@Html.MyCachedPartial("PartialView", Model2, 60, cacheKey: "model2key", cacheByPage: true)
```

EDIT:

From version 7 there is an overload for `CachedPartial` that allows the key to be passed in

```
public static IHtmlString CachedPartial(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, 
    string partialViewName, 
    object model, 
    int cachedSeconds, 
    bool cacheByPage = false, 
    bool cacheByMember = false, 
    ViewDataDictionary viewData = null, 
    Func<object, ViewDataDictionary, string> contextualKeyBuilder = null);
```

The use case for this would be:

```
@Html.CachedPartial(
    "PartialView", 
    MyModel3, 
    3600, 
    cacheByPage: true,
    contextualKeyBuilder: (model, viewData) =>
    {
       return (model as MyViewModel).Id.ToString();
    });
```

Comment: @SnakeEyes great - that works for version 7+. if you want to use that approach there is no need for extension method, it can be written directly, see my edited answer - if you want to simplify it :)